# What is the meaning of !"?

Tags: shell, quoting

The command `echo !"` returns an error message. But the command `echo "Hello!"` succeeds. Is it correct to use the command `echo "Hello!"` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `echo "Hello!"` will print `Hello!` to standard output.

Comment: @AndyDalton But one book says it will return an error message.

Comment: Read `man bash` about history expansion, and then think about why history expansion doesn't work inside quotes. Also, make sure to use the correct quotes `"` (and not `”`).

Comment: @dirkt, history expansion _works_ within double-quotes. Try e.g. `echo "!hello"`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running Bash, the `!` triggers [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html). If it's on, and you write e.g. `!echo`, it gets replaced by the last command starting with `echo`. The feature is originally from csh, I don't know what other shells support it.

History expansion isn't the smartest of features, and e.g. `!"` will trigger it, even though it seems to always fail (running `"echo" foo` and then trying `!"` still fails). Annoyingly, it also triggers inside double-quotes, e.g. in `echo "!hello"`. In Bash 3.2, `echo "hello!"` would also trigger it, but apparently that's changed in newer versions.

My suggestion would be to turn the thing off, put `set +o histexpand` or `set +H` in your Bash's startup files.

Comment: In bash 5.0, !" will succeed after runninng "echo" foo.

Comment: @tmpbin, ah ok, so that's been changed too